# please help me get sharedpreferences saved value from other class

Tags: android

I am saving the value in sharedPreferences in one Class and trying to access it from another
class but get null pointer exception. the value that i enter is url for web service. please help me.

UrlSetting.java

```
public class UrlSetting extends Activity {
EditText editUrl;
TextView Savedurl;
Button bSaveUrl, bback;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.urlsetting);

    Savedurl = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.savedurl);
    editUrl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editurl);
    bback = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
    bSaveUrl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveurl);
    bSaveUrl.setOnClickListener(buttonSaveUrlOnClickListener);
    bback.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(UrlSetting.this, Login.class);
            /*intent.setClass(UrlSetting.this, Login.class);*/
            startActivity(intent);
        }});

    LoadPreferences();
}
Button.OnClickListener buttonSaveUrlOnClickListener
= new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SavePreferences("URL", editUrl.getText().toString());
        LoadPreferences();
    }

private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

private void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String strSavedurl = sharedPreferences.getString("URL", "");
    Savedurl.setText(strSavedurl);
}
```

and this is my Koneksi.java

```
public class Koneksi{

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
String url = sharedPreferences.getString("URL", "");
public Koneksi(String urlml){

    url= url + urlml;
}

public String getUrl(){

    return url;
}
```

this is the LogCat

```
> 05-21 11:39:44.542: W/KeyCharacterMap(339): No keyboard for id 0
05-21 11:39:44.542: W/KeyCharacterMap(339): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
05-21 11:39:51.826: D/TryLoginCheck(339): Here
05-21 11:39:51.826: I/System.out(339): UserNametes
05-21 11:39:51.831: I/System.out(339): passwordTes12345*
05-21 11:39:51.831: D/Parameters(339): username=tes&password=Tes12345*
05-21 11:39:51.831: D/AndroidRuntime(339): Shutting down VM
05-21 11:39:51.831: W/dalvikvm(339): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:146)
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at mobile.config.Koneksi.<init>(Koneksi.java:13)
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.karismaelearning.Login.tryLogin(Login.java:131)
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.karismaelearning.Login$3.onClick(Login.java:80)
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-21 11:39:51.851: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 11:39:54.301: I/Process(339): Sending signal. PID: 339 SIG: 9
```

please help me to know what the mistake is. I don't understand what's wrong. thank you very much

Comment: Where do you get null pointer? Please post logcat so we can help you easier

Comment: @codeMagic, I already edited my question with the LogCat. Thank you

Comment: What is at line 131 of `Login`? That's where your error is

Comment: @codeMagic, linkurl = new Koneksi("/Login.php"); this is line 131...

Comment: I'm sorry, the error is in `Koneksi Activity`. See my answer. I believe it will fix your problem

Comment: @codeMagic, I already try your answer but I still got same error :(... for Koneksi i didn't make any layout because it just save the value. and i use it to other class like Log in.

Comment: What is line 13 of `Koneksi`? Also, if you aren't using a `layout` then you don't need to `extend Activity`. Just pass `context` to the class and use that to access your `SharedPreferences`. They are available app-wide but they require a `context`

Comment: @codeMagic, line 13 is public Koneksi(String urlml){ ,this line is before i edited. if I didn't put extends Activity in there the MODE_PRIVATE get red... so, i just try to put in there,because i don't know what i must put for preferences.. sorry, this is first time i make preferences so I don't really understand how to do it...

Comment: @codeMagic, can you give me the one the use context, please? because i don't understand where i must apply it. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  // your code..
}

private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

private void LoadPreferences(){

    String strSavedurl = sharedPreferences.getString("URL", "");
    Savedurl.setText(strSavedurl);
}
```

---

Edited:

```
    public class Koneksi{

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    Context myC;
    String url = "";

    public Koneksi(Context con){
       myC = con;
       sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(con);
    }


    public Koneksi(String urlml){

        url= url + urlml;
    }


    public String getUrl(){
        String url = sharedPreferences.getString("URL", "");
        return url;
    }
}
```

for call above class from activity:

```
Koneksi ob = new Koneksi(this);
String URL = ob.getUrl();
```

Comment: i got error for koneksi class, but for koneksi class i didn't use layout. so how to call the preferences? O.o

Comment: for urlSetting class, am i must erase the MODE_PRIVATE and change it become like ur ans or not? O.o and for string url = sha... is it after public string get url? because for the public koneksi got red.. or i must put it in both? O.o

Comment: i can't understand what you are trying to say. but just use my code.

Comment: hmm, i got error at url =url +urlml, it got red mark.. O.o thank you

Comment: add this String url = ""; after Context myC; check my edited ans

Comment: It success!! thank you very much.. but in every class like Login. java when i call it Koneksi linkurl = new Koneksi("/Login.php"); String SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl(); it got error.. every class has own .php, so how i can call it? O.o thank you

Comment: for this no need to set url every time just store base url. like i have many php file at www.abc.com/webs/ then i save only "www.abc.com/webs/". after String URL = ob.getUrl(); i add like URL += "login.php" or "register.php" whatever page name. so, now my URL is 'www.abc.com/webs/login.php' or 'www.abc.com/webs/register.php'

Comment: add your activity name before this like: Koneksi ob = new Koneksi(MainActivity.this); where MainActivity is my activity name

Comment: may I ask again? i got error when i type that Koneksi linkurl = new Koneksi (this) in public void Onclick.. one of my class has that   
`public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try
{linkurl = new Koneksi(this);
SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl();
SERVER_URL += "uploadProses.php?idc="+param1+"&idtgs="+param2+"&idu="+param3;...`
it say : The constructor Koneksi(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined 
what is the solution? Thank you

Comment: oops, sorry the answer is above my question because i edited my question and got deleted, but thank you very much once again @Dhawal.. it works :D

Comment: may I ask again? I try to write like this `String urlws = "/mobile/"`, mobile is my folder for my php. and i write `url = url + urlws + urlml` and got error what is the correct one? i want to make like that, so the user only insert www.abc.com . i think it's easier for the client. thank you

Comment: instead of this use: url += urlml; where urlml = "/mobile/login.php"

Comment: Dhawal, may I ask u another question in here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953355/got-error-when-try-to-download-pdf-file . If you have time, please look at that question, because I really need help and I don't know where is my mistake. thank you

Answer (score 0):

try these two methods :p works well

```
public static void SavePreferences(String key, String name, String value,Context c) {
    SharedPreferences sf = c.getSharedPreferences(key, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sf.edit();
    editor.putString(name, value);
    editor.commit();
    Log.w("Preference saved  .", value);

}

public static String LoadPreferences(String key, String name, Context c) {
    SharedPreferences sf = c.getSharedPreferences(key, 0);
    String val = null;
    val = sf.getString(name, "");
    return val;

}
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally frowned upon on SO. Please explain your answers so people will know why your code should work

Answer (score 0):

These will give you `NPE`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);                                                          
String url = sharedPreferences.getString("URL", "");
```

Move the initializations to `onCreate()` which I don't see but assuming you have since you are extending `Activity`

```
public class Koneksi extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences; //declare them here
    String url;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

       sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);  // initialize them here
       url = sharedPreferences.getString("URL", "");  // intialize here

    public Koneksi(String urlml){   
        url= url + urlml;
    }
```

`SharedPreferences` needs a `Context` which isn't available until after `onCreate()` is called. You can declare them before this as you are but you need to initialize them in `onCreate()` or another `Activity` method after `onCreate()`is called

Comment: where I must put the context? O.o

Comment: Use the `Context` like `context.getSharedPreferences*"MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVVATE);` You can pass it to a constructor of the class like MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this);

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I couldn't respond sooner but I had to get to sleep...it was late for me

Comment: hi codeMagic may I ask another question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882865/i-need-help-have-error-when-receive-messages-chat , I really need help to solve this because i don't know where is my mistake. if you have time please look at that question. thank you very much

Comment: codeMagic, can you help me with this question, it still about the chat. i already know the problem is on the stream, the stream always empty can't get the content, but i don't know to solve it. if you have time, please look at this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983482/unable-to-receive-chat-messages   .thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
   - you should be pass the context 



   mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);




  other wise use following code :-
  import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  // then you use
  prefs.getBoolean("keystring", true);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. "you can do so in a non-Activity ..." what does this refer to?

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreference is common over your application you can use anywhere in your application,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what is the problem with your code, i have working implementation for same..

```
    public class GreetingCardData {
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_FILE     =   "greetingCardData";
    public static final String KEY_DO_NOT_SHOW      =   "doNotShow";
    public static final String KEY_CATEGORIES_JSON  =   "categoriesJson";   
    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    private Editor prefsEditor;

    public GreetingCardData(Context context) {
        this.sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_FILE, 0);
        this.prefsEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    }   

    public void setDoNotShowFlag ( boolean flag ){
        prefsEditor.putBoolean( KEY_DO_NOT_SHOW, flag );
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public boolean getDoNotShowFlag(){
        return sharedPrefs.getBoolean( KEY_DO_NOT_SHOW, false );
    }

    public void setGreetingcardJson( String jsonString ){
        prefsEditor.putString( KEY_CATEGORIES_JSON, jsonString );
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getGreetingcardJsonString(){
        return sharedPrefs.getString(KEY_CATEGORIES_JSON, "");
    }    
}
```

and you can access your pref. anywhere by just calling it like..

```
if( !new GreetingCardData(ActivityMain.this).getDoNotShowFlag())
     startHomeActivity();   


new GreetingCardData(context).setGreetingcardJson(resBuffer.toString());
```