# unable to receive chat messages

Tags: java, php, android

I have problem and need help when receive messages for the chat i make, i only success to send the messages and show the messages that i send, but i failed to receive and show the messages that i receive from other party.  
I can't retrieve the messages from database and always null, when the messages come the code not checking there is any messages and null and i think it's stop.  
and I checking the stream, the stream can't get the content.  
 
i don't understand what's wrong, so anyone please help me. thank you

chatroom.php

```
    <?php
 include "config.php";
   $idu= $_REQUEST['idu'];
   $idch= $_REQUEST['idch'];

    if($idu && $idch){
       $sqlString = " SELECT a.id, a.message, a.system, b.id, b.name, b.course, c.id, d.firstname FROM mdl_chat_messages 
                    as a inner join mdl_chat as b on b.name=a.chatid inner join mdl_course as c on c.id=b.course 
                    inner join mdl_user as d on d.id=a.userid and a.system = 0 and a.userid='".$_GET['idu']."' 
                    and a.chatid='".$_GET['idch']."' and a.id='".$_GET['idcm']."'";}

    $res = mysql_query($sqlString);
        if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0)
        {
            while($data = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $msg = $data["message"];
                echo "$msg";
            }
        }


?>
```

Chatroom.java

```
package mobile.chat;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.*;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import mobile.config.CourseHttpClient;
import mobile.config.Koneksi;

import com.karismaelearning.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
/*import android.util.Log;*/
/*import android.os.Handler;*/
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class ChatRoom extends Activity {
    public Koneksi linkurl;
    String SERVER_URL;
    private EditText messageText;
    private TextView meLabel;
    private TextView friendLabel;
    private ViewGroup messagesContainer;
    private ScrollView scrollContainer;
/*    private Handler handler = new Handler();*/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chatpage);

        messagesContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.messagesContainer);
        scrollContainer = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollContainer);

        Button sendMessageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        final String paramnama = bundle.getString("nama");
        messageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEdit);
        meLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meLabel);
        friendLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.friendLabel);
        meLabel.setText(paramnama + " (me)");


        final String param1 = bundle.getString("keyCourseId");
        final String param2 = bundle.getString("keyUserId");
        final String param3 = bundle.getString("keyChatsId");
        final String param4 = bundle.getString("keyMessagesId");

        receiveMsg();
        sendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("messages", messageText.getText().toString()));

                String response = null;

                try {
                    linkurl = new Koneksi(ChatRoom.this);
                    SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl();
                    SERVER_URL += "/mobile/ChatKirimTeks.php?idu="+param2+"&idch="+param3;
                   response = CourseHttpClient.executeHttpPost(SERVER_URL, postParameters);

                   String res = response.toString();

                   res = res.trim();

                   res = res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                   if(res.equals("1")){
                       String messageString = messageText.getText().toString();
                       showMessage(messageString, true);
                       messageText.getText().clear();
                   }else
                   {
                       createDialog("Maaf", "Messages Anda Gagal Terkirim");
                   }
                }

                catch (Exception e) {

                    messageText.setText(e.toString());  

                }

             }

        });}


        HttpURLConnection connection;
    URL url = null;
    try{
        linkurl = new Koneksi(this);
        SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl();
        SERVER_URL += "/mobile/ChatRoom.php?idu="+param2+"&idch="+param3+"&idcm="+param4;
        url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);
        //ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //add parameter
            //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

            HttpResponse httpRespose = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpRespose.getEntity();

            //read content
            InputStream in = httpEntity.getContent();
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String msg = "";
            while(true)
            {

                try {
                    msg = read.readLine();
                    Log.d("","MSGGG:  "+ msg);

                    //msgList.add(msg);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.getMessage();
                }
                if(msg == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    showMessage(msg, false);
                }
            }}
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        }


    public void showMessage(String message, boolean leftSide) {
        final TextView textView = new TextView(ChatRoom.this);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setText(message);

        int bgRes = R.drawable.left_message_bg;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        if (!leftSide) {
            bgRes = R.drawable.right_message_bg;
            params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        }

        textView.setLayoutParams(params);

        textView.setBackgroundResource(bgRes);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                messagesContainer.addView(textView);

                // Scroll to bottom
                if (scrollContainer.getChildAt(0) != null) {
                    scrollContainer.scrollTo(scrollContainer.getScrollX(), scrollContainer.getChildAt(0).getHeight());
                }
                scrollContainer.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }
        });
    }

    private void createDialog(String title, String text) {
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setMessage(text)
        .create();
        ad.show();
    }
}
```

LogCat

```
    06-04 17:42:55.932: I/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.karismaelearning/mobile.chat.ChatDetail (has extras) } from pid 410
06-04 17:42:56.762: I/ActivityManager(61): Displayed com.karismaelearning/mobile.chat.ChatDetail: +816ms
06-04 17:42:57.392: I/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.karismaelearning/mobile.chat.ChatRoom (has extras) } from pid 410
06-04 17:42:57.802: D/(410): MSGGG:  null
06-04 17:42:58.334: I/ActivityManager(61): Displayed com.karismaelearning/mobile.chat.ChatRoom: +862ms
```

Comment: Again string concatenation in SQL statements... **USE PREPARED STATEMENTS**, damnit. Passing raw strings into an SQL API should be punishable by law.

Comment: @fge, sorry can you explain what did you mean? i don't understand..

Comment: In your PHP code, when you generate the SQL statements, you concatenate arguments taken from the request parameters directly. This is the typical vector of SQL injection attacks. Use something like PDO (this is the only one I know) to build prepared statements, this avoids this kind of attacks.

Comment: owh so it is like that, sorry I just newbie and i just know how to make the codes like that.. thank you for the advice..

Comment: Well honestly, I can't really blame you; there are WAY TOO MANY tutorials on the net that demonstrate string concatenation for generating SQL, and FAR TOO FEW that demonstrate the use of prepared statements :/

Comment: @fge, yeah, i just learn from book like that so i just know to make it like that hehe. hmm, may I ask you? can you help me to know what's wrong with my code, I always got null in the content. thank you